# Writing a Data to Matrikon OPC UA Server

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I have using matrikon flex ua sdk server for opc ua server and conect this server via python. I can connect server and get value of a node. But when i want to write a value to a variable in server, it gives me

> 'DataValue object has no attribute set_value'

error message.

In the [client_examples.py](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/master/examples/client-example.py) script , there are examples to write value to server like what i do. Help please?

This is the error: [image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do node.set_value instead of myStoredVariable.set_value.

Comment: when i try to: `myStoredVariable_node.set_value(ua.Variant([23], ua.VariantType.UInt32))`  or   `myStoredVariable_node.set_value(2)` , it gives me 'BadTypeMismatch: The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute"s value.(BadTypeMismatch)' , why?

Comment: In OPC UA, the type must match precisely when writing. I do not know what the type of your variable is. You need to match them. For example, you may need ua.VariantType.Int32, or ua.VariantType.UInt16, or something else -depends on the server configuration. Anyway, this a different problem that should be under different SO question. Originally you had a compilation error; now you are actually already writing into the server, it's just that the server rejects it with an error.

Comment: `myStoredVariable_node.set_value(ua.Variant(23, ua.VariantType.UInt32))` works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the server side you can not modify the whole variables. Some variables can be only readable. You probably try to modify readeable variable.

Try to read the variable. Can you read properly and also you can use UAExpert Software. It is OPC-UA cilent. You can access whole variable and you can see the variables readable and writeable.

Comment: Hi, i want to read and write in client side. With python api , i can read value, but can not write. When i look at the server side, this variable readable and writable.